# how to generate more than one value in a QR using ZXing in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, xamarin

I'm using ZXing to generate a QR code. A single value makes it perfect, but I don't know how to generate more than one value.

This is my code

```
public partial class MyQR : ContentPage
    {
        ZXingBarcodeImageView qr;

        public MyQR(string value1, string value2, string value3)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            qr = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            qr.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            qr.BarcodeOptions.Width = 400;
            qr.BarcodeOptions.Height = 400;
           
            qr.BarcodeValue = ????????;
            
            XAMLQR.Children.Add(qr);
        }        

       
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: a QR code, like any barcode, is just an encoded string.  If you want more than one string to be encoded, then you just concatenate them together, using a delimiter if you like.